# Sending custom fields as an array in a Zendesk app

Tags: javascript, zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I'm developing an app in Zendesk. At some point I'm creating a new ticket. Here is the relevant code:

```
createTicketValues: function(){
    var newTicket = {};
    newTicket.ticket = {};
    ...
    newTicket.ticket.custom_fields = [{id: 25064823, value: document.getElementById('25064823').value},{id: 360011962831, value: document.getElementById('360011962831').value}];
    ...
    app.createTicket( newTicket);
},
createTicket: function(ticketData){
    console.log(ticketData);
    var request = 
    {
        url: '/api/v2/tickets.json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ticketData
    };

    client.request(request).then(function (data){
        app.addParentToProject();
    })
},
```

However, the new ticket doesn't have any of these custom fields. Which is strange because:

I'm also adding other fields (ticket form id, priority...) which are saving correctly

If I only save one field like this:

```
    newTicket.ticket.custom_fields = {id: 25064823, value: document.getElementById('25064823').value};
```

or like this

```
    newTicket.ticket.custom_fields = {id: 360011962831, value: document.getElementById('360011962831').value};
```

One custom field saves correctly (but I have to choose to save one or the other)

Am I doing something wrong when declaring the array?

To me, it looks the same as what's described in their documentation (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets#setting-custom-field-values) but I've been a few hours trying to fix it and haven't been able to.

Comment: Can you check the network console and confirm what is the request data being sent?  Is it being lost before the request gets sent to Zendesk or after?  Would also be curious if you can make the same request via cURL and confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states to place the id and value properties inside double quotes - could you give that a try? Otherwise the contents seem to be ok.

```
newTicket.ticket.custom_fields = [{"id": 25064823, "value": document.getElementById('25064823').value},{"id": 360011962831, "value": document.getElementById('360011962831').value}];
```

Comment: It is inside double quotes because the documentation is using cUrl which takes a JSON. My code shouldn't need quotes as it's passing the object directly to a function (client.request) which should still work and is working for all the other fields (that are not passed as arrays).
I tried to add double quotes just to make sure and the result is the same.